# Xcode Master-Detail storyboard multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

Using Xcode's default `Master-Detail` template.  I've added 2 `cells` to the `TableView` in `MasterviewController`.  I'd like each cell to open a different `ViewController` while maintaining the navigation functionality (ie: the `button` to open `master` `ViewController` again).  Some of the examples I've seen involve putting a if statement in the `prepareForSegue` method and using the segue's identifier to pick which `ViewController` to use, but I'm confused as to how you link everything together with the `NavigationController`.

[image]

Comment: u can simply ctrl drag the first  cell to first view controller , and second cell to second controller

Comment: yes but then I lose the nav control after entering a view controller from the cells.

Comment: no you wont. Your tableview has navigation controller, you can simply do push to both first and second controllers.

Comment: Perhaps I'm using the wrote segue, but if I use show detail, I lose the nav control.

Comment: do you need only 2 cells ?

Comment: No, I plan on more.  Used two for the example to keep it simple.

Comment: you dont need a nav controller to go to first or second. As you plan to have more cells, you should have only one table cell on your tableview, and your tableview contains protottype cells. you can point the segue to first view controller,instead of first navigation controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://pulkitgoyal.in/side-drawer-navigation-for-ios/

Link to a nice tutorial with example to create the effect I'm looking for using the MMDrawerController library available here:  https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController